# python - Add a number to an integer inside a nested list

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

This is  MWE of what I'm trying to do:

```
lis = []
# Initialize empty list
for i in range(2):
    lis.append([[0]]*2)

# First print
print lis

# Second print
print lis[0][1][0]

# Modify item
lis[0][1][0] += 1

# Third print
print lis
```

The **first** `print` returns the list as `[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]` which is correct, I have a first list which is composed of several lists, each one also composed of several lists (I need this nested lists for what I'm doing). The **second** `print` returns the item in indexes 0 and 1 as `0` which is also correct. But the **third** `print` shows me the new list as:

```
[[[1], [1]], [[0], [0]]]
```

instead of:

```
[[[0], [1]], [[0], [0]]]
```

which is what I actually aimed at. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, [this vizualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=lis+%3D+%5B%5D%0A%23+Initialize+empty+list%0Afor+i+in+range(2)%3A%0A++++lis.append(%5B%5B0%5D%5D*2)%0A%0A%23+First+print%0Aprint+lis%0A%0A%23+Second+print%0Aprint+lis%5B0%5D%5B1%5D%5B0%5D%0A%0A%23+Modify+item%0Alis%5B0%5D%5B1%5D%5B0%5D+%2B%3D+1%0A%0A%23+Third+print%0Aprint+lis&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=0) makes it obvious why this works as it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is happening because both inner lists are actually copies of same object, so modifying one will affect the other one as well.

```
>>> l = [[0]]*2
>>> [id(x) for x in l]
[145328716, 145328716]             #same IDs
>>> l[0].append(4)
>>> l
[[0, 4], [0, 4]]
```

Use a list comprehension to avoid that:

```
>>> l = [[0] for _ in xrange(2)]
>>> [id(x) for x in l]           #Different IDs 
[145327372, 145327500]
>>> l[0].append(4)
>>> l
[[0, 4], [0]]
```

Comment: Well, that was quick :) Thank you Ashwini!